# Select bars in a plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to select part of a plot in Shiny UI? I would like to give user the possibility to select range of bars in plot and apply some function based on selection.

I did not find any example, but maybe someone has a working solution to this use čase.

Comment: I guess, this link might be of interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023342/interactive-plotting-in-shiny-using-mouse-clicks/28035861#28035861.